# Java printing issues using Java api

Tags: java, printing

using this java api : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html

i have tried to modify this code for my needs, currently i have :

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import java.io.*;
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.*;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.*;

 public class pdfPrinter {

    public static String CompletefileName; // calls from FileUploadController

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        FileInputStream psStream = null;
        try {
            psStream = new FileInputStream(CompletefileName); // this calls a location where the pdf file is stored
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) {
            ffne.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (psStream == null) {
            return;
        }
        DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(psStream, psInFormat, null); // unsure what psStream is, not explained in the api, want to use this to print pdfs, will look at more 
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psInFormat, aset);
        aset.add(new Copies(5)); //sets copies, will add this as a vairable so users can change this
        aset.add(Sides.DUPLEX); // same as above
        if (myPrinter != null) { // having issues setting myPrinter
            DocPrintJob job = myPrinter.createPrintJob();
            try {
                job.print(myDoc, aset);

            } catch (Exception pe) {
                pe.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("no printer services found"); //error msg
        }
    }
}
```

Currently this does not compile as i do not know how to set `myPrinter` to the default printer on my machine, also this will be for a jsf web app, can i run this from a push of a button on the web page ?

is this the right way of doing this to print a pdf ? any advice or tutorials will be really helpfully

Comment: where is 'myPrinter' defined ???

Comment: it is not defined yet, as i do not know how to set this to a printer, what is needed so it can set the default printer to be `myPrinter`

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the javadoc for `DocPrintJob`,which is an interface. So `myprinter` would have to be an object which implements that interface.

From there it seems like you can attach a printer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/DocPrintJob.html

This might help as well as it gives an example:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/jpsOverview.fm4.html

Answer (score 0):

You should define as

```
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, null);
PrintService myService = null;
for(PrintService service : services) {
    System.out.println(service.getName());
    if(service.getName().contains(user.getDefaultPrinter())) {
        myService = service;
        break;
    }
}
```